# Finding some explicit formula for $(ab)^n$ in any $a,b$ in a finite $p$-group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups

> If $G$ is a finite $p-$group, let $a$ and $b$ any two elements from $G$.
>
> Is there any formula for $(ab)^n$ involving $a^nb^n$ for any natural number $n$? That is, some formula like $(ab)^n = a^nb^nf(a,b)$ for some function of $a$ and $b$.

Please not those "modulo" some subgroups formulas! Like $$
(ab)^n \equiv a^nb^n \pmod{H},
$$
where $H \leq G$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you mean something like $(ab)^n=a^nb^n$ ?

Comment: I know this is not true for all cases, I mean some thing $a^nb^nf(a,b)$

Comment: I suppose Hall's collection process is not good enough for you, right?

Comment: @AndreasCaranti, do you mean the one involving commutators?

Comment: @A.Messab It is difficult to work out what you want. In $p$-groups, and more generally nilpotent groups, the formulaes usually involve commutators. For example, if $G$ is nilpotent of class at most two then the identity $(xy)^m=x^my^m[y, x]^{m\choose2}$ holds. Which is really pretty. You can generalise this to groups of higher class, but the cost here is more commutators.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti Do you mean the work in Section 12.3 of M. Hall's book? (Or is it something of e.g. P. Hall?)

Comment: @user1729 There is a general formula due to Hall and Petrescu (I don't have the book by Hall on hand to see if that is the one). It is referred to as the Hall-Petrescu formula in Berkovich's book on $p$-groups.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Okay, thanks. It has a [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall%E2%80%93Petresco_identity). Its due to P. Hall and Petrescu, and seems to be the stuff in M. Hall's book (although the statements are related but quite different and I am not going to work out just now if they are actually equivalent).

Comment: @user1729 Thnak you very much for your example and explanation, I wish you give me some "detailed" reference bout this.

Comment: Before voting to reopen this Question, I'd like to see concrete information added to the problem such as the presentation for the subgroup generated by $a,b$.  Without that I don't understand how a mathematical argument can be advanced.

Comment: @hardmath But the reason for closing the question was "unclear what you're asking", which I don't understand at all - it's completely clear what the question is asking.

Comment: @DerekHolt:  I was not involved in closing the Question, and "unclear what is asked" is often confounded with "missing details or other context".  The Comments seem to point to some articulable Answer, so I'm persuaded by your opinion ("it's completely clear") to cast a reopen vote.  That said, I could construct a trivial Answer, just doubtful that it would help the OP or other Readers.

Comment: @hardmath well I thought the answer was just no, but that does not mean that the question is unclear! The general Hall-Petrescu formula is probably unhelpful because it involves unknown elements $c_i$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some formulas* and they involve (often unknown) commutators. Sometimes there are particularly nice formulas, but they hold in $p$-groups and for things of the form $(ab)^{p^n}$, so they do not hold for arbitrary powers.

Some example formuals are:

1. If $G$ is nilpotent of class at most two then the identity $$(xy)^m=x^my^m[y,x]^{m\choose2}$$ holds. Which is really pretty. You can generalise this, via the Hall-Petresco formula, to groups of higher class, but the cost here is more commutators.
2. If $G$ is any group then we have the [Hall-Petresco formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall%E2%80%93Petresco_identity), as mentioned in the comments: $$x^my^m=(xy)^mc_2^{m\choose {2}}c_3^{m\choose {3}}\cdots c_{m-1}^{m\choose {m-1}}c_m.$$ Here each $c_i$ is contained in the $i^{th}$ subgroup of the decending central series for the group $G$. See Section 12.3 of M. Hall (1959), *The theory of groups*, Macmillan, MR 0103215. This book also contains some useful formulas for regular $p$-groups. Note that it is Philip Hall after whome the formula is named, while Marshall Hall wrote a book (and did other stuff too!).

You can find other formulas in the first section of the book C. Leedham-Green, S. McKay (2002) *The Structure of Groups of Prime Power Order*, Oxford University Press, and also in the book Y. Berkovich (2008) *Groups of Prime Power Order Volume 1* (Appendix 1 of this book proves the Hall-Petresco formula).

*or formulae, if you want to be correct but also sound slightly pretentious :-)

Comment: Thanks this is so helpful